# Associating File Extensions to a files with variable extensions

Tags: windows, file-extension, file-association

In Windows, I have a set of files in a folder that all have similarly formatted text content, but with different extensions based on a timestamp. For example, assume two files named data.20140424 and data.20140423 for two days. Each day brings a new file with a new extension.

Is there a way to associate all the extensions with a single program that can view the files? Do I need to have a registry entry for each extension? Is there an alternative way to associate files besides extension, like with mime type or full filename?

Answer (score 0):

You need a registry entry for each file. If you're on windows, double-click the file, select the program to open it with. Make sure "use this program every time" checkbox or similar checkbox is checked. It will open and you won't need to do this again.

Comment: Since I'm working with many files, I'm looking for an alternative to associating each file individually manually. If any new files with new extensions were added, I would need to associate them individually.